# Magento Problem - out of stock

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I'm probably the last poblem with my shop . I have 5 in stock products "TEST" . I see them in the store, but I can not change their status from "OUT OF STOCK " on the other. By this I do not buy the product test to see how it works. How can I do this?
And how can set the ability to order things from outside the store ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check setting at `ADMIN: System → Configuration → Inventory Tab`. Magento is provide the feature of setting start  no out of stock qty

Qty for Items’ Status to become Out of Stock — Specifies the products’ quantity in stock to be considered as out of stock. By default, this value is set to 0. However, you may decide not to sell off products, but to keep some quantity available in your store